# How to tell when control becomes visible for the first time?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, viewstack, tabnavigator

I have a popup that contains a TabNavigator control. The tabs are dynamically added to the TabNavigator when the popup loads. Is there a good way to tell when one of the tabs is loaded, from the tab itself?

I have a tab that requires a service call to be made, and I don't want the service call to be made unless the user actually goes and clicks the tab to view it. I *could* notify the tab from the popup control itself when the TabNavigator index was changed, but that doesn't seem like a good way to go about doing it. I'm wondering if there's an event or something I could hook to that would let me know the tab needed to be rendered for the first time (from within the tab control itself). Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I didn't quite understand the question, so I'm trying again. I think this code will address your problem.

The trick is setting the creation policy to "none" for the component. Flex will create the tab, but not the component itself.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" creationComplete="onCreationComplete()" layout="vertical" minWidth="955" minHeight="600">
<mx:TextArea id="log" width="100%" height="500"/>

<mx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import mx.containers.Canvas;
        import mx.events.FlexEvent;
        private function onCreationComplete():void{
            var canv:Canvas = new Canvas();
            canv.label = "One";
            canv.addEventListener(FlexEvent.CREATION_COMPLETE,onCreateTab);
            canv.creationPolicy="none";
            tn.addChild(canv);
            canv = new Canvas();
            canv.label = "Two";
            canv.addEventListener(FlexEvent.CREATION_COMPLETE,onCreateTab);
            canv.creationPolicy="none";
            tn.addChild(canv);
            canv = new Canvas();
            canv.label = "Three";
            canv.addEventListener(FlexEvent.CREATION_COMPLETE,onCreateTab);
            canv.creationPolicy="none";
            tn.addChild(canv);
        }

        private function onCreateTab(event:Event):void{
            log.text+=event.currentTarget.label+ " created for the very first time\n";
        }
    ]]>
</mx:Script>    
<mx:TabNavigator id="tn" width="500"/>
</mx:Application>
```

Comment: Replace `Canvas` with a spark `NavigatorContent` control and this doesn't work for some reason. Definitely threw me off for a bit. I guess I'll just have to use a `Canvas` unless you know any reason why that might be. Thanks for the solution.

Comment: For some reason I thought you were still using Flex 3, my bad. Are you one 4 or 4.5?

Comment: Interesting, within SkinnableContainer.as (navigatorContent's parent) I found that setting creation policy actually doesn't take affect properly... in the "creationPolicy" setter it sets the value to Auto if it's none and sets a flag! It then stores the actual creation policy in a CSS var via setStyle. It does this to avoid inheritance of that property because Spark and MX handle it differently. I don't have a quick solution for you unfortunately.

Comment: No problem, you've shed enough light on the situation already! Thanks for looking into it a bit more.

Answer (score 1):

There's an event called the "FlexEvent.SHOW" event which should work for you. See: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/events/FlexEvent.html#SHOW

You can put this on the TabNavigator. i.e.

```
<mx:TabNavigator>
   <comp:SomeComp show="doSomething()" label="My Tab"/>
</mx:TabNavigator>
```

Or you can put it inside your component. i.e.

```
<mx:Canvas show="doSomething">
<!-- My Component-->
</mx:Canvas>
```

If you're creation policy is set, you can also do this on creationComplete, but it will only happen the FIRST time the tab is created.

Running example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" layout="vertical" minWidth="955" minHeight="600">
    <mx:TextArea id="log" width="100%" height="500">

    </mx:TextArea>
    <mx:TabNavigator width="500">
        <mx:Canvas label="One" show="{log.text+='One Clicked\n';}"/>
        <mx:Canvas label="Two" show="{log.text+='Two Clicked\n';}"/>
        <mx:Canvas label="Three" show="{log.text+='Three Clicked\n';}"/>
        <mx:Canvas label="Four" show="{log.text+='Four Clicked\n';}"/>
    </mx:TabNavigator>
</mx:Application>
```

With dynamic tabs.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" creationComplete="cc()" layout="vertical" minWidth="955" minHeight="600">
<mx:TextArea id="log" width="100%" height="500">

</mx:TextArea>

<mx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import mx.containers.Canvas;
        import mx.events.FlexEvent;
        private function cc():void{
            var canv:Canvas = new Canvas();
            canv.label = "One";
            canv.addEventListener(FlexEvent.SHOW,onShow);
            tn.addChild(canv);
            canv = new Canvas();
            canv.label = "Two";
            canv.addEventListener(FlexEvent.SHOW,onShow);
            tn.addChild(canv);
        }

        private function onShow(event:Event):void{
            log.text+=event.currentTarget.label+ " clicked\n";
        }
    ]]>
</mx:Script>

<mx:TabNavigator id="tn" width="500">
</mx:TabNavigator>
</mx:Application>
```

Comment: Won't the show event fire every time the tab is clicked?  He only wanted to run this code the first time the tab was clicked; not every time.

Comment: Actually, this one doesn't appear to fire when the tab is clicked. It works off the "Visible" property, which doesn't get set to false just because the tab isn't currently selected.

Comment: The show event has always worked for me on tabNavigators, but not its component children. The only other event I could think of would maybe be something with focus?

Comment: I just did a test with this code, code posted in first comment. Worked fine.

Comment: I believe your example produces different results because you are not dynamically loading the tabs.

Comment: I just tried it with dynamic tabs and it still worked... posted code above again.

Answer (score 0):

Read up on the [Flex Component LifeCycle](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/ascomponents_advanced_2.html).  Based on what you describe, I would probably listen for the creationComplete event on the tab's content.

Comment: Unfortunately, creationComplete is called when the tab is added to the navigator, not when it is being displayed in the navigator for the first time.

Comment: @Ocelot20 I wasn't sure, sorry.  The TabNavigator does weird thing w/ deferred instantiation, where the 'child/tab source' will be created, but not the children's children or something like that.  I don't use the component enough to have that stuff down pat.  You could use updateComplete and use a flag to tell whether or not you already have the data.  Except I bet updateComplete will fire right after creationComplete.

Comment: You are correct, updateComplete also gets called when the content is added. Perhaps this is not easily accomplished and I should just notify the tab from outside.